# Custom Date Formatting in J2ME

Tags: date, java-me

I would like to format a J2ME Date object to only show the date part, not the date and time.  What would be the easiest way?  Would probably need to include an external library to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Calendar` has all the methods required to format a date output.

Comment: look for calendar there for examples : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-rms/